# DPDT Polarity Switch

Tags: motor, relay, polarity, reverse-polarity, dpdt

I am trying to connect a USB relay to actuator, so when I press button 1 , motor goes up, when i press button 2, polarity is switched and motor goes down.

I am trying to achieve this with a DPDT relay. Someone gave me this diagram, however, when i press button 1 motor goes down, but nothing happens when I press button 2. What did I miss ?

[image]

Useful info :
Actuator = Motor, connecting 2 at the same time so they both run together

USB Board = USB Relay, but has physical buttons. I have a 4 channel relay, only 2 are used. When I Press button 1 in front of channel 1, motor should go forward, when I press button 2 in front of channel 2, polarity should reverse, thus motor moving backward.

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It has symbols for switches and relays. It will produce a legible schematic and by the time you have finished drawing it neatly you might spot your problem.

Comment: Forgive me I have very little electrical knowledge - i couldn't figure out using the tools, that was the best I could do

Comment: I really can’t figure out that diagram, but if you have two SPDT relays independently controlled that is enough for forward/reverse/stop control.

Comment: (1) What is "actuator"? (2) Why does your diagram have two actuators? (3) Why have you two relays on the USB board and a DPDT relay as well? (4) "*when i press button 1 ...*" Where are buttons 1 and 2? (5) "*nothing happens when I press button 2.*" Nothing? No relay click or LED on the USB board? Please [edit] your **question** to supply all the missing information. Don't bury essential information in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated the post

Comment: You missed question (3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxhKxj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. All you need.*

How it works:

- With RLY1 and RLY2 de-energised both ends of the actuator motors are connected to negative. They won't move.
- With RLY1 and RLY2 energised both ends of the actuator motors are connected to positive. They won't move.
- If only RLY1 is energised it supplies the positive connection and RLY2 supplies the negative. The motors will run forwards.
- If only RLY2 is energised it supplies the positive connection and RLY1 supplies the negative. The motors will run backwards.

Comment: Very grateful for your reply ! So there is no need for the DPDT rely at all, I would just use the relay on the USB Rely board ?

Comment: I've updated with a schematic for each state. Read through the answer again to make sure you understand it. Can you think of any reason that it wouldn't do what you want? Don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question to your satisfaction.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can do it with just the USB relay board